# syntax error unexpected token bash scripting

Tags: bash

I am getting a few of these errors in my bash script. I am new to the language. Any pointers?

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Calculating the value V for all given values"
inflation=(0 0.03 0.05)
tax_rate=(0 0.28 0.35)
for I in inflation
do
        for R in tax_rate
        do
                V=(4000*((1+0.07*(1-R))/(1+I))^10)
                echo -n "$V "

        done

done
```

This is my output:

Calculating the value V for all given values
./investment.sh: line 9: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./investment.sh: line 9:`              V=(4000*((1+0.07*(1-R))/(1+I))^10)'
 ./investment.sh: line 12: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
./investment.sh: line 12:`     done'

Comment: The error comes from the `((` inside the assignment. `V=(....)` defines `V` as an array of words, as in `V=( x y z )`, and the for the parser, an unquoted `(` inside the list can't be handled. You could write  `V=('4000*((1+0.07*(1-R))/(1+I))^10')`, which would make `V` a one-element array holding a string representation of this formula, but then I wonder why you need an array, if it has only one element. You could simply use a scalar: `V='4000*((1+0.07*(1-R))/(1+I))^10'`.

Comment: If you really want to do floating point arithmetic in a shell, you could convert your script to zsh, which has float variables.

Answer (score 1):

1. always test your code to https://shellcheck.net on errors (you have too much `do` statements)
2. `bash` can't compute floating numbers itself, use [bc](/questions/tagged/bc) <sup>[1]</sup> instead
3. to do arithmetic substitution, use `$(( ))`
4. to do arithmetic, without arithmetic substitution, use `(( ))` form
5. UPPER CASE variables are reserved for system, better use lower case
6. `inflation=(0 0.03 0.05)` is an array, you can access it via `"${inflation[@]}"`
7. quote variables ! <sup>[2]</sup>

<sup>[1]</sup> [bc](/questions/tagged/bc)

```
bc <<< "scale=2; (4000*((1+0.07*(1-$r))/(1+$i))^10)"
```

<sup>[2]</sup>
Learn how to quote properly in shell, it's very important :

> "Double quote" every literal that contains spaces/metacharacters and *every* expansion: `"$var"`, `"$(command "$var")"`, `"${array[@]}"`, `"a & b"`. Use `'single quotes'` for code or literal `$'s: 'Costs $5 US'`, `ssh host 'echo "$HOSTNAME"'`. See
> http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes
> http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Arguments
> http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/words

Command Substitution: "$(cmd "foo bar")" causes the command 'cmd' to be executed with the argument 'foo bar' and "$(..)" will be replaced by the *output*. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/002 and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/CommandSubstitution

`$((...))` is an arithmetic substitution. After doing the arithmetic, the whole thing is replaced by the value of the expression. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ArithmeticExpression

`((...))` is an arithmetic command, which returns an exit status of 0 if the expression is nonzero, or 1 if the expression is zero. Also used as a synonym for "let", if side effects (assignments) are needed.

### Finally

```
#!/bin/bash
  
echo "Calculating the value v for all given values"
inflation=(0 0.03 0.05)
tax_rate=(0 0.28 0.35)
for i in "${inflation[@]}"; do
    for r in "${tax_rate[@]}"; do
        v="$(bc <<< "scale=2; (4000*((1+0.07*(1-$r))/(1+$i))^10)")"
        echo -n "$v "
    done
done
echo
```

## Output

```
Calculating the value v for all given values
7840.00 6480.00 5920.00 5360.00 4400.00 4000.00 4400.00 4000.00 3600.00
```

Comment: Instead of `$(())`, you can also use `((x=a+b))`.

Comment: Both solutions added

Comment: The array access should be double quoted (probably harmless when it contains just numbers, but...)

Comment: I'd recommend against using `echo -n`, since some versions just print "-n" as part of the output (I had an OS update break a bunch of my scripts once...). Use `printf '%s ' "$v"` instead.